# How Can i pace a producer actor so that it does not pump to many message to a consumer actor

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

I have an actor that generates UpdateItemMessage , this message is consumed by multiple child actors . my problem is the Producer is faster than the consumer actors and it generates far more messages than the child actors can consume, for that reason i want to pace the producer . What i tried to do is use Become() and Unbecome() to indicate busy/idle status.  What is the best practice for the parent/producer to query the status of child actors .

- Producer calls Ask for each item in Context.GetChildren() ?
- Consumers Tell Producer when they switch their status to busy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. And doing something like this would arguably be easier once the streaming API has been properly ported to akka.net.

So for example lets say your producer is an actor that reads something from a file on disk. Where each line/item represents some work that needs to be 
done. That you distribute across multiple workers.

I would let the workers send an ack message back to the producer (via Sender.Tell).

I would then let the producer read the lines in batches of a fixed size (for example 500). After that it schedules the next batch to be read by scheduling a message to itself. (via scheduler
That way you free up your producer actor by enabling it to recieve ack's from your worker actors.
You could then keep state in your producer actor on how much it has send out, and how much work is done.

At that point its easy to determine if your workers are ready for the next batch of work, or that you need to wait a bit.

An alternative to this is that you communicate with your workers via a proxy actor. That does the throttling for you. (the same way as in the producer example, by keeping record of how much work is done in combination with worker ack's).
The downside to this is that the throttler actor would effectively buffer all messages the producer will throw at it.

Comment: that is exactly what i am doing i have a large json file (1-2GB) , i am using JsonReader to read each node and construct messages which in turn gets consumed by the child actors . I like your idea of scheduling the next batch read, but because this is a big json data , i don't want to abandon my current read position/depth. i guess maybe i should convert the json to TSV or  CSV then process it.

Comment: well if you store the JsonReader instance in the actor. Instead of doing a while jsonReader.Read() you can use a for loop. And cleanup the jsonreader instance when your done. or on actor PostStop.